# Acceleration velocity relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I just happened to come across this specific question in physics:-

> Q: If a particle is moving along a straight line with increasing speed, then,
>
> (1) its acceleration is negative
>
> (2) its acceleration maybe decreasing
>
> (3) its acceleration is positive
>
> (4) both (2) and (3)

My physics teacher said that as such all the options are correct but as the option in the book is given to be (4), mark this as the answer only.
So, my doubt is that I agree with the options 2,3 and 4 but this option 1 to be true for the given statement is confusing me a little. Please justify the 1 option to be true in this case for me.

Comment: Acceleration is a vector quantity. As such it depends on the way you define your coördinate system. If you have a particle moving along the x-axis but in the negative direction, and if that particle is accelerating, than your acceleration will be negative.

Comment: If all statements where correct, then statement (1) and (3) would form a paradox.

Comment: Pardon me, but it is your responsibility to justify your answers and ours to comment upon your reasons.  If you think (3) is true, why are you confused by (1), which is the opposite of (3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where the issue lies is the question is asking about *speed* - not velocity.

Speed is defined to be the absolute value of velocity, and is a scalar quantity. Thus, the first case could work if the velocity is negative and the acceleration is negative. This way, the velocity would decrease, becoming more negative, but the absolute value of velocity, or speed, would increase.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of acceleration is change in speed with time, and if the speed is *increasing*, by definition acceleration is positive.

Think of continually adding the quantity of acceleration to speed. If you add a positive number it makes the result a bigger number, if you add a negative number it makes the result a smaller number.

Over a tiny fraction of time $\Delta t$ speed changes by $$\Delta v = a \Delta t$$ where $a$ is the acceleration. If $a$ is positive then $\Delta v$ is positive because time always flows forward ($\Delta t>0$)